# Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'date_added

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

**Model Class**

@Entity
public class Watchlist {

```
    @Id
    private String scrip_name;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
    private Date date_added; 
    private double recom_price;  // recommended price
    private double stop_loss;
    private double curr_price;   // current price
    private double lmar;  // low made after recommended price
    Getters and Setters and toostring   
}
```

**Service Class**

```
public interface WatchlistService {
    
    Watchlist saveWatchlist(Watchlist watchlist);
    void deleteWatchlist(Watchlist watchlist);
    List<Watchlist> getAllWatchlist();

}
```

> Blockquote
> **Controller**

@Controller
public class WatchlistController {

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
    }

    @Autowired
    WatchlistService service;
    
    @RequestMapping("/createWatchlist")
    public String showcreate() {
        return "createWatchlist";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/savewatchlist")
    public String savewatchlist(@ModelAttribute("watchlist") Watchlist watchlist, ModelMap modelMap) 
{
        Watchlist watchlistSaved = service.saveWatchlist(watchlist);
        String msg = watchlistSaved.getScrip_name(); 
        modelMap.addAttribute("msg", msg);
        return "createWatchlist";
    }
}
```

I am trying to fet the date from jsp and insert into mysql

Below is the code snippet from jsp file

```
Date Added:<input type="date" name="date_added"/>
```

Comment: Please add some details to your question, like exceptions and its stack trace.

Comment: Make sure that the format of date you are getting from JSP is the same as u declare here `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");`  else share the exceptions and stack trace.

Comment: Field error in object 'watchlist' on field 'date_added': rejected value [2020-09-19]; codes [typeMismatch.watchlist.date_added,typeMismatch.date_added,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [watchlist.date_added,date_added]; arguments []; default message [date_added]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'date_added'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: ]

Comment: Try to pass field as well like this `webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class,"date_added", new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));`

Comment: if that doesn't work then Change : `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")` to @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")

Answer (score 0):

From the comments section logs the exception is related to parsing of the date.

> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not
> parse date: Unparseable date: ]

It looks like the date string coming from the jsp is not in the format defined in initBinder.

You need to ensure the formats are same.

Just for test purpose change the backend date format as same as jsp and check if it works.

The format you are sending is 2020-09-19

The format in initBinder is MM/dd/yyyy 09-19-2020

So obviously it won't work. Change the format in either of one side and it works.

Comment: its already there
  @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
    }

Comment: its already there in controller, do i need to change anything else
  @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
    }